# No conversion from text to arraybuffer when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, base64

I'm trying to fetch the file using ajax and add download Data URI using dummy a tag. I'm using this lib [jquery.binarytransport.js](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/blob/master/BinaryTransport/jquery.binarytransport.js)

and when I try to fetch pptx document with binary or arraybuffer option:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    var dataURI = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa(data);
}, 'binary');
```

or

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
    var dataURI = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa(data);
}, 'arraybuffer');
```

I've got error `"No conversion from text to binary"` or `"No conversion from text to arraybuffer"` the same happen with blob.

and when I set type to text I've got error when I use btoa function on the response: `"Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."`

Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve the issue by using text as responseType and using this function:

```
function base64(buffer) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
}
```